# Why wouldn't C# support generics of generics (generics with parameterized types)?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, generic-collections, nested-generics

Recently (perhaps of design shortcomings) I faced a regular task when required to have a collection of `MyType<T>` where `T` is not fixed (i.e. multiple various generics instantiations throughout one collection).

As it's widely proposed (for such cases) an abstract class was declared:

```
public abstract class MyType {}
public class MyType<T>: MyType {}
```

and then I'm having a collection of `MyType`.
However for this collection I had a constraint of having no more than one element for any type `T`.

Hence, I made a bit of custom implementation of `ICollection<TBase>`.
I wanted to include there a method `Get<TParam>()` for getting an item corresponding to type `TParam`. To be later used like:

```
MyCollection<MyType> collection = new MyCollection<MyType>();
MyType<int> myInt = collection.Get<int>();
```

However I unexpectedly discovered that I can't even declare it:

```
public TCustom<TParam> Get<TParam, TCustom<TParam>>() { } //this won't compile
```

because inner generics (or so-called "generics of generics") are neither supported by C# nor by .NET (I suppose). How do you think, were there any specific reasons behind such limitations (except for complexity)?

**UPDATE 1.** Asked for compiler version and compiler errors.

Microsoft C#, .NET 3.5 (Visual Studio 2010).
Errors:

> error CS0081: Type parameter declaration must be an identifier not a
> type
>
> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TCustom' could not be
> found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**UPDATE 2.** Asked whether I need a fix or explanations why. I really wanna know **WHY**. But if you have good solutions to the problem, you are also welcome.

**UPDATE 3.** The question might be answered already in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2011/03/15/net-c-generics-history-some-photos-from-feb-1999.aspx). It appears that CLR team was under big pressure not to overcomplicate the language.

Comment: please also add the compiler error you're getting

Comment: This can only be answered by the C# Team at Microsoft. If you're lucky one of them will see this Q, but really this isn't the kind of question that SO works with: you're asking for an opinion.

Comment: Are you asking *why* this is a limitation (and I'm not entirely sure I understand what you want to begin with, it was quite convoluted the scenario you described here), or *how* to fix this?

Comment: Lasse, I am pretty sure it can't be fixed without deeper redesign. Hence I will appreciate any good solutions, but I am more interested why, perhaps Microsoft kept smth on its mind when limiting this.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could put together a short but complete code sample that illustrates the error. As it is, I can't determine what your `TCustom` class is supposed to be, so I'm at a bit of a loss trying to figure out what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: Jim, nothing special about this type. TCustom<> is supposed to be MyType<>.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you could simply hide the data in a non-generic dictionary:

```
private Dictionary<Type, object> _Data;
```

and then your `Get` method:

```
public MyType<TParam> Get<TParam>()
{ 
    return (MyType<TParam>)_Data[typeof(TParam)];
}
```

If the `TParam` types aren't related, there is no common data structure that will give you type-safety anyway, so why even try?

Comment: A type-safe approach for newer versions of .NET would be to have a static class `MyTypeDataHolder<T> where T:class` which contains a `ConditionalWeakTable<MyType,T>`  Then `MyType<TParam> Get<TParam>` could fetch data from `MyTypeDataHolder<T>.table[this]`.

Answer (score 0):

Why exactly do you need

```
public TCustom<TParam> Get<TParam, TCustom<TParam>>() { }
```

When the generic type (MyType in your case) is known, can't you just do

```
public MyType<TParam> Get<TParam>() { 
  return (MyType<TParam>)_items.FirstOrDefault(i => i is MyType<TParam>);
}
```

Or am I missing something?

Comment: Maxem, it would be alright if I was implementing ICollection<MyType>.

But I'm rather implementing a generic collection, hence don't wanna get coupled to specific type instantiations.

However, of course, I can create an extension-method for MyCollection<MyType> with the implementation you provided. But it is a bit frustrating because it eliminates a generic approach.

Comment: Besides, the details of implementation of my collection can (probably) give me a result faster than using FirstOrDefault(), e.g. when I'm using a Dictionary internally.